# Target specific project on msbuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I want to target a specific project's target while still building the entire solution.  According to [this MSDN post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171486.aspx), the following should work:

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /t:Build /t:src\Api\MyProject_Api:FileSystemPublish /p:PublishConfiguration=Release /p:PublishOutputPathNoTrailingSlash="C:\a"
```

But I get the following msbuild error:

```
error MSB4057: The target "src\Api\MyProject_Api:FileSystemPublish" does not exist in the project.
```

Solution:

[image]

I am using MSBuild 14.0

Comment: The post states 'project name', did you try that instead of giving the path?

Comment: @stijn: Yep, this is what I have in my post, unless I am mistaking you?

Comment: Sorry should have been more clear: you use `src\Api\MyProject_Api` now, so try with just the project name which is `MyProject_Api`

Comment: @stijn: Ah yes, I did try that. Same problem.

Comment: Just tried it here and the results are weird: the `folder\project:target` syntax works for `rebuild` and `clean` targets, but not for `build` for instance. Might be a bug, I'd report it as such on Microsoft Connect and see what they have to say about it

Comment: Ah yes, build does work.  Can you think of another way around this problem?

Comment: Not really, except first building the entire solution then using msbuild to invoke the target in the project directly, for example `msbuild src\Api\MyProject_Api.csproj /t:FileSystemPublish`

Comment: @stijn: this is what I was trying to avoid as it's for CI (prolongs the build). Thanks